# Why is DateFormat.format(date) giving a different time than date.toString()?

Tags: java, date

I am observing this strange behavior in my code -

```
Date executionDate = execDao.getExecutionDate(id);
System.out.println(executionDate);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(executionDate));
```

This gives the output

```
2014-03-05 22:10:46.0
2014-03-05 10:10:46
```

Why the difference in the hours in the output?

Comment: `22:10` ==> `10:10 pm`

Comment: hh represents 1-12 and HH represents 24 hour format. Change hh to HH and see.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Duh! I'm clearly having a bad day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first method gets 24 time by default. The second one gets 12 hour time because that's what you specified. Change the second function call to
 `SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");` to get 24 hour format.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Can't believe I didn't spot that.